# Execute javascript inside the div element ajax updates

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I have some ajax scripts in my page that updates a certain part of the page. The thing is that the output is updated in a div element that renders any javascript written in it completely useless.

The scripts written in that div are written with php code and are dynamic and not static (so including them into the main page is not an option).

The basic constuction is this:

```
<div id="someid">
  <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    // some code that is dynamically created with php and is not working
    //]]>
  </script>
  <!--Some html code that is dynamically created with php-->
  <!--The html code created needs that script above-->
  <!--Possibly more scripts that are...-->
  <!--you guessed it! Dynamically created with php-->
</div>
```

Possible result:

```
<div id="someid">
  <script type="text/javascript">
  //<![CDATA[
  $(function() {
    $( "#20" ).datepick({dateFormat: 'yyyy-mm-dd'});
  });
  //]]>
  </script>
  <input id="20" type="text" name="somename" maxlength="10" />";
</div>
```

^All of the above values may change dynamically on user input.

Example of the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
  function showsubs()
    {
    var xmlhttp;    
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
  else
    {// code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("someID").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
  xmlhttp.open("GET","give.php",true);
  xmlhttp.send();
  }
//]]>
</script>
<input type="button" onclick="showsubs()">
<div id="someID"></div>
```

Where give.php is the simple:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    $( "#inputField2" ).datepick({dateFormat: 'yyyy-mm-dd'});
  });
<br /><br />
<input type="text" size="12" id="inputField2" />
```

---

I have also tried this: (I mark every script inside the div with that class)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
console.log("start");
function evalme()
{
  console.log("eval");
  var a=document.getElementsByClassName('scriptttorun');
  console.log(a.length);
  for (var i=0;i<a.length;i++)
{ 
eval(document.getElementsByClassName('scripttorun')[i].innerHTML);
}

}
$('document').ready(evalme());//I call evalme on other circumstances as well

        //]]>
    </script>
```

But eval does not activate my functions..

Comment: Have you tried to put script before the end of close div? And maybe if you provide some example of output help us to understand better the problem

Comment: @keypaul I edited my question just now. I need the script placed at the top so I can use the functions in it in the html code that is located afterwards. The problem is that javascript cannot be executed inside the div element so I need to do something about that.

Comment: can you provide your script or part of it

Comment: @keypaul: I just added an example.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to fetch the code as plain JavaScript. On your AJAX success handler try to `eval` the script you received back.

This is what most of the remote JavaScript inclusion plugins do. Though when you do this, you need to know the exact effect of closures, scopes in JavaScript.

---

Method 1:

If you can use jQuery, then the best way would be to use the following method:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "test.js",
  dataType: "script"
});
```

This will request `test.js` (you can use `javascriptgenerator.php` too).

If `script` is specified, `$.ajax()` ***will execute the JavaScript that is received from the server before passing it on to the success handler as a string***.

---

Method 2:

The `eval` method. Try giving an ID to your script tag:

```
<script id='someID'>
     //your dynamic javascript
</script>
```

Now after you inject your JavaScript into your div, you could do the following:

```
eval(document.getElementById('someID').innerHTML);
```

Lemme know which method you chose.

Comment: Can you add an example in your answer please?

Comment: @dx4, added two examples, you could use any one you like :)

Comment: The thing is that the script is not static. In the example I have posted the #20 maybe #5 or #putanynumberhere. Also there maybe more scripts. EDIT : I'll try the second one and get back to you.

Comment: Yes, and I am sure that you are loading this JavaScript via some AJAX call to a php file right?

Comment: Yes, and the php creates the script. I'll try the second solution because I can put an id ta on the scripts I create.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52271/discussion-between-sunny-r-gupta-and-dx4)

Answer (score 0):

You can check if jquery is loaded

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
(function(){
    var checkIntv;
    function checkJQuery(){
        if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined') {  
           checkIntv = setInterval(function(){checkJQuery()}, 100);
           console.log('wait...');
        } else {
            clearInterval(checkIntv);
            console.log('do something');
            $( "#20" ).datepicker({dateFormat: 'yyyy-mm-dd'});
       }
   }
checkJQuery();
}());
//]]>
</script>
```

But what kind of error you have? $ undefined? or else?

Comment: Javascript simply does not run when it is inside a 'div' element. I have jQuery imported into the page.

Comment: Problably i don't understand right. Anyway an online test here http://www.roughdesign.it/sof/test-date/

Comment: I've added an example in my question. I hope you'll understand now.